# Constructing the character table of Octahedral Group (order 48)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters, irreducible-representation

I am trying to construct the character table for the symmetry group of Cube, $O_h$, which as 48 elements. I figured out that there are 10 classes. Now, as a consequence of the great orthogonality theorem, I have $\sum l_i^2 = 48$ ...(1), and the number of irreducible representations is equal to the number of classes. So , I tried solving the equation (1), for $a_1, a_2,...a_{10}$ keeping a condition that $a_i \leq a_{i+1}$, to avoid repetitions. i am getting only 6 possible solutions.
Integer solutions satisfying the conditions:
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5]

But I need 10 IR's. So how do I find the remaining ones?

Also, In the examples I have come across, they usually deal with $C_{nv}$ or $D_n$, which are relatively smaller groups, so they usually have one solution to equation (1). Here, there are 10, so do I construct 10 different character tables?

Comment: I think you are confused. There is only one character table, not 10. The character table has 10 rows and 10 columns (assuming your count of 10 classes is correct - I have not checked that). When you solve the equation $\sum l_i^2 = 48$ you get all the possibilities for the character degrees (the first column of the character table) but only one of them is the correct one. Also, the solutions you have listed have only 9 values even though you said you found 10 classes.

Comment: A few comments to help you. As Ted said, your solutions contain only $9$ numbers. The number of characters of degree $1$ is equal to the order of the abelianization $G/[G,G]$ of the group, which is $4$. In fact the octahedral group is isomorphic to $S_4 \times C_2$, so you could just compute the character tables of $S_4$ and $C_2$ and combine them in the standard way.

Comment: @Ted Sorry for the miscalculations. I have found the 10 classes. I took the first one to be 1 itself, but still made an error in the code, I guess. I rechecked it and got Integer solutions satisfying the conditions:
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6]
these as the solutions. As you said, there is only one correct. How do I go about checking that?

Comment: @DerekHolt I am new to representation theory, so could you suggest some references to understand how to construct character table of $G$ from $g_1xG_2$. That would be really helpful. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: There is a standard result that every irreducible (complex) character of a direct product $G \times H$ is the product of irreducible characters of $G$ and $H$. This arises from the tensor product of the corresponding representations. Sorry I cannot immediately point you to a reference - try searching.